# Go GORM failed to guess relations for embedded types

Tags: go, orm, model, go-gorm

For some cases I need to extend my standard models with computed data. E.g. display information about the existence of some DB values in the UI. I do this by creating an extended model via type embedding like so:

```golang
/* Standard Models */

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string
    Documents []*Document // has-many
}

type Document struct {
    gorm.Model
    User             *User // belongs-to
    UserID           uint
    Name             string
    DocumentFulltext *DocumentFulltext // has-one
}

type DocumentFulltext struct {
    gorm.Model
    Document   *Document // belongs-to
    DocumentID uint 
    Fulltext   string
}

/* Extensions */

type DocumentListEntry struct {
    Document       `gorm:"embedded"`
    FulltextExists bool
}
```

My query then looks like this:

```golang
queryConnection := DBConnection
queryConnection = queryConnection.Joins("left join document_fulltexts on documents.id = document_fulltexts.document_id")
queryConnection = queryConnection.Where(`"documents"."user_id" = ?`, userID)
queryConnection = queryConnection.Select(
    `"documents"."user_id",
    "documents"."name",
    CASE WHEN "document_fulltexts"."fulltext" IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS "fulltext_exists"`,
)
documents := []DocumentListEntry{}
queryConnection.Table("documents").Scan(&documents)
```

This is the error I get:

```
[error] failed to guess DocumentFulltext's relations with DocumentListEntry's field DocumentFulltext 1 g false
```

A full demo can be found here: https://github.com/go-gorm/playground/pull/62

How do I need to construct the extended model to make this work?

Is this approach recommended at all? Whats the best-practice here? Any alternatives I should consider?

Thx!

Comment: Can you try adding a tag like this `Document \`gorm:"embedded"\``?

Comment: Tried it, error still happens. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: I would like to preload DocumentFulltext and create DocumentFulltext after fetching document

Comment: @perelin were the tables created using `gorm.Automigrate`? Also, please include some mock data so that it's easier to test this

Comment: I added a gorm/playground link with full demo code and mock data. -> https://github.com/go-gorm/playground/pull/62 - All tables were created by `gorm.Automigrate`.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks: I´m not exactly sure what you mean by "preload DocumentFulltext and create DocumentFulltext after fetching document" - I actually try not to load the complete fulltext table since it can get pretty big :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in GORM. Fixed in Version v0.2.27.

GORM issue here: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3224